# "filmed her on their cellphones" or "filmed her with their cellphones"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

- filmed her **on** their cellphones
- filmed her **with** their cellphones

?

I see both forms, but I am not sure why that is, and if one is preferred over the other. 'On' seems to sound better, but logically 'with' seem to make more sense. Is there any difference in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general they are equivalent in meaning but there are circumstances when they differ.

If I film her on my cellphone then it is unambiguous that I am filming here and I am using for that purpose my cellphone.

If I film her with my cellphone then I might be making a film of her carrying my cellphone.

In general though the context would make it clear what is happeneing in the *with* version.

Perhaps worth adding that cellphone is US English, in the UK we have *mobiles* but I think most people would say they were filming on their smartphone or use its brand-name. I know you did not ask about dialect differences but it might be of some use some other time.